# Making my Service accessible using intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I want my service to be accessible as one of the default options of the `Share page` when the user long-touches the web-link (standard android feature). This is what I wrote in the manifest file :

```
<service android:name=".ShareLink"
            android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But it is still not being displayed. What am I doing wrong? P.S. When I do the same thing with the Activity - it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, You will have to write a Dummy Activity to do this.

This is because, `ResolverActivity` that shows the names or selects the appropriate component to launch gets the list by querying Only `Activities` that match intent with API  `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities`

Comment: Add an activity with above intent filter, if its a small job do it in oncreate and call finish() in Oncreate. If its a bigger job, start service in activity and again call finish() in Oncreate itself

Comment: @Dennis: an Activity doesn't have to have a UI. You can load an Activity and do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<intent-filter
    android:label="Open Using My Service">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```